# How do I change the values of an array using a for-in loop inside a function or a nested function?

Tags: arrays, swift

Running through the swift 2.0 documentation and Im trying to practice some stuff I learned in c++. One of which is the ability to modify array elements inside of my element which I am having trouble doing in swift.

```
 var scoreOfStudents = [86, 93, 68, 78, 66, 87, 80]

 func returnScoresWithCurve (inout scoresOfClass : [Int]) -> [Int] {
      for var score in scoresOfClass {
          if score < 80 {
              score += 5
          }
      }
      return scoresOfClass
 }
```

Don't know what my error is because in the for-in loop, the scores less than 80 are being added but aren't being modified in the array I passed. Also would like to know how I can do this same thing using a nested function and not for-in loops.

Answer (score 21):

I believe that using a for-in loop like this, your score variable is value copy of the array element, as opposed to a reference variable to the actual index of your array. I would iterate through the indices and modify `scoresOfClass[index]`.

This should do what you're looking to do.

```
var scoreOfStudents = [86, 93, 68, 78, 66, 87, 80]

func returnScoresWithCurve(inout scoresOfClass: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    for index in scoresOfClass.indices {
        if scoresOfClass[index] < 80 {
            scoresOfClass[index] += 5
        }
    }
    return scoresOfClass
}
```

Also, why are you you using `inout scoresOfClass` when you're returning?

Comment: Use `..<` instead of `-1`.

Comment: Or even better: `for index in scoresOfClass.indices`.

Comment: thanks! this worked but @Mario Zannone 's solution is much more simple and cleaner

Answer (score 13):

@ChrisMartin is correct: changing score you are simply changing a copy of the value, not the original in the array, and the approach with the index will work.

Another, more *swifty* solution is the following:

```
func returnScoresWithCurve (scoresOfClass : [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return scoresOfClass.map { $0 < 80 ? $0 + 5 : $0 }
}
```

Here `returnScoresWithCurve` will return a modified array instead of changing the original. In my view this is a plus.

Comment: talking about code cleanliness, Thanks for the nice answer! Now Im on to figure out how I can use a nested function and do this problem

Comment: Better answer than the loopy one.

Answer (score 0):

Another IMO beautiful solution in Swift:

```
 var scoreOfStudents = [86, 93, 68, 78, 66, 87, 80]

 func returnScoresWithCurve (inout scoresOfClass : [Int]) -> [Int] {
      for (index, score) in scoresOfClass.enumerated() {
          if score < 80 {
              scoresOfClass[index] = score + 5
          }
      }
      return scoresOfClass
 }
```